TextField using ViewThatFits does not show keyboard
When ViewThatFits is used with a text field and the HStack should be shown, SwiftUI seems to retain the VStack layout.  Additionally, tapping on any text field to present the software keyboard only works when the VStack layout is presented.
In the case where the HStack layout should be shown, tapping on a text field returns the following in the console:

-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID. inputModality = Keyboard, inputOperation = <null selector>, customInfoType = UIEmojiSearchOperations

struct ContentView: View {
@State var text1 = ""
@State var text2 = ""

    @ViewBuilder var content: some View {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .font(.system(size: 100))
        Text("Hello")
            .font(.system(size: 50))
    }
    
    var textfields: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("text1", text: $text1)
            TextField("text2", text: $text2)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits {
            VStack {
                content
                textfields
            }
            
            HStack {
                content
                textfields
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }

}


I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4 simulator. It changes to a HStack as expected and the keyboard works normally.

Does not work on the 17.4 simulator either.  Tested on device with 17.3 and no difference.
https://imgur.com/a/q6JZPbl
